# Generating different chart results on fly causes flickering

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to filter chart results using PHP and JavaScript. I started off building one and got it to how I wanted so I moved onto building the filtering functionality for generating different results for the charts and I managed to get them to generate how I wanted. However, my problem is when I change my select inputs the charts generate and change but they flicker by rendering back and fourth between one another and I'm not entirely sure why?

My assumption is I'm possibly creating another chart on my input change which might be causing the bug?

Here is my code:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.collapse').collapse()

  var colors = [];
  // Global Colors to Generate Random Color
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
      g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
      b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
      c = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
      colors.push(c);
  };

  var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');

  $(document).ready(function(){
   var delivered = document.getElementById('delivered');
   var chartContainer = document.getElementById('chartContainer');
  })

  // Delivered Accordion Filter
  function totalChange(){
   switch(delivered.options[delivered.selectedIndex].value){
    case "Total Results":
     canvas[0].id = "totaltoolkits";
     var ctx = document.getElementById("totaltoolkits");
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
           type: 'bar',
           data: {
               labels: <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>,
               datasets: [{
                   label: 'Total Results',
                   data: <?php echo json_encode($count) ?>,
                   backgroundColor: colors,
               }]
           },
           options: {
               scales: {
                   yAxes: [{
                       ticks: {
                           beginAtZero:true,
                           fontSize: 12
                       }
                   }],
                   xAxes: [{
                       ticks: {
                           beginAtZero:true,
                           fontSize: 12,
                           autoSkip: false
                       }
                   }],
               }
           }
       });
     break;
    case "Today":
     canvas[0].id="todaytoolkits";
     var ctx = document.getElementById("todaytoolkits");
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
           type: 'bar',
           data: {
            labels: ['second', 'Chart', 'GenerationTest'],
               //labels: <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>,
               datasets: [{
                   label: 'Second Test',
                   data: [1, 2,],
                   backgroundColor: colors,
               }]
           },
           options: {
               scales: {
                   yAxes: [{
                       ticks: {
                           beginAtZero:true,
                           fontSize: 12
                       }
                   }],
                   xAxes: [{
                       ticks: {
                           beginAtZero:true,
                           fontSize: 12,
                           autoSkip: false
                       }
                   }],
               }
           }
       });
     break;
    case "Yesterday":
     canvas[0].id="yesterdaytoolkits";
     break;
    case "Last 7 Days":
     canvas[0].id="last7daystoolkits";
     break;
    case "Last 30 Days":
     canvas[0].id="last30daystoolkits";
     break;
    case "This Month":
     canvas[0].id="thismonthstoolkits";
     break;
    case "Custom Range":
     canvas[0].id="customrangetoolkits";
     break;
    default:
     canvas[0].id="totaltoolkits";
   }
  }
 </script>
<body>
 <div class="fluid-container">
 </div>
  <div class="container">
   <h1>Metrics</h1>
   <div class="row">
    <!-- Accordion -->
   <div class="accordion" id="accordionColumn">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              <span id="description">Delivered Toolkits</span>
            </a>
          </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionColumn">
          <div class="card-body" id="cardOne">
           <select
       class="form-control"
          name="delivered" 
          id="delivered"
       onChange="totalChange()"
          >
           <option selected disabled>Filter By:</option>
           <option value="Total Toolkits">Total Toolkits</option>
           <option value="Today">Today</option>
           <option value="Yesterday">Yesterday</option>
           <option value="Last 7 Days">Last 7 Days</option>
           <option value="Last 30 Days">Last 30 Days</option>
           <option value="This Month">This Month</option>
           <option value="Custom Range">Custom Range</option>
          </select>
           <div id="chartContainer">
             <canvas class="displayChart" id=""></canvas>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>    
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had this problem too. You can't re-assign fresh data. You have to make sure you're mutating the existing datasets objects. I don't have the code on me, but hopefully that makes sense. If you do this, chartjs will animate it nicely.

Comment: I see. Yeah I was looking at the browsers element source and noticed that when a chart gets created, it creates another div right above it with styles and such I had that assumption also. So in short, I cannot modify the `canvas` id at all I have to modify the datasets based on the select input conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new chart or re-assigning `datasets`, you have to mutate the existing datasets to get them to animate nicely.

e.g.

```
const chart = new Chart(ctx, { ... });
//chart.datasets = [/* new datasets */] // bad! won't animate
chart.datasets[0].data = [/* new data */] // good!
chart.update();
```

Comment: got it. Thank you